# Android studio calculator Dot button

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make a simple calculator but when I press on dot button "." the result is like this
1....1
but I need it to be like this
1.1

this is my code

```
bdot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ans.setText (ans.getText()+"."); 
  }   
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us the code you have written, that is giving this error.

Comment: Thanx alot ... this is the code : bdot.setonclickListener(new view.onclickListener() { @override publicvoid onclick(view v) { ans.setText(ans.getText()+"."); }  });

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code and all other relevant details!

Answer (score 0):

Set the EditText to NumberDecimal

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/calculator"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```